# Antd: How to custom close icon and search icon style?

Tags: search, antd

I have a problem when custom  close icon and search icon style.
I want to make search icon in left of input and close icon in right of input.
But now two icons is in right of input.

[image: A search box with an X and search icon on the right, with the search icon partially outside of the search box]

How can I fix this problem?

My code is here

```css
.ant-input {
            padding: 4px 10px 4px 40px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            &-search {
                height: 40px;
                width: 240px !important;
            }
            &-suffix {
                width: 18px;
                > i {
                    font-size: 18px;
                }
            }
        }
 }
```

```html
<div className='user-list__tollbar--search'>
   <Search
        onChange={this.onSearch}
        style={{width: 200}}
        defaultValue={keyWord}
        allowClear
    />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use antd `Input` to solve your issue

```
<Input
  prefix={<SearchOutlined />}
  placeholder="Search"
  allowClear
/>
```

[image: Screenshot]